# Applescript–execute multi line code

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript, osascript

I have some apple script code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 97
end tell
```

How do i write the code as a `osascript -e` command in Terminal?
Everytime I try using `\n` or the such, I get errors. Sorry if I'm not being specific enough.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Pass each line of the AppleScript code as a separate -e option:

   ```
   osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'key code 97' -e 'end tell'
   ```
2. Pipe the AppleScript code to osascript's STDIN:

   ```
   osascript <<END
     tell application "System Events"
       key code 97
     end tell
   END
   ```

Oh, and you can also save AppleScript code as an executable shell script. Just add `#!/usr/bin/osascript` at the top of the code and save it as a plain text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
  key code 97
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Other example:

```
  open -a Terminal && \
     sleep 2 && \
     osascript -e 'activate application "Terminal"' -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "q" using command down'
```

the first two lines are just to show the final goal, which is focus the Terminal window and quit it, sending Command+q

Answer (score 1):

Actually `-e` option accepts new lines:

```
osascript -e '
tell application "System Events"
    key code 97
end tell'
```